# Thunderbird GnuPG + Enigmail: encryption command failed

Tags: macos, encryption, thunderbird, gnupg

Yesterday Thunderbird complained that I used GnuPG 1.x and the next update of TB would not work with this version. So I upgraded my Mac (OSX 10.10 Yosemite) to GnuPG 2. Now I see that TB has a new Enigmail menu bar on top of the new mail window, which would be really nice, if I could send signed mail. But I can't.

When I try to send a signed mail, I get the error Encryption command failed. I get no popup requesting to enter my password to sign the mail.

When I try to open the setup wizard I get another XML error:

```
XML-parse error: asynchrone entity
Locatie: chrome://enigmail/content/enigmailSetupWizard.xul?skipIntro=true
Linenumber 384, column 20:      <description>&enigmail.keygen.desc;</description>
-------------------^
```

I've noticed that in the past week I've sent several emails to persons who don't use GPG, don't have a public key, and both mails were encrypted while I haven't entered my password. So how is this possible?

So how can I fix these errors?

Comment: Gpg2 might have installed new encryption rules - check if you don't need to generate a new key. And what OS are you on?

Comment: I'm going to try that. It's a Mac by the way!

Comment: I'm totally lost here. There's GnuPG, GPG, and Enigmail. GPG has a list of my private keys and public keys of others. Enigmail is the interface between Thinderbird and the keys. I can see this list in Enigmail as well. I guess Enigmail is not the problem here? I suppose that GnuPG is used as a behind-the-scenes tool to create keys and encrypt and decrypt? Is that about right? Which keys do I have to regenerate? If I create a new private key, won't that result in loss of encrypted messages with the old key? I don't see any warnings or messages that I should regererate anything.

Comment: I just opened the .gnupg folder and saw that all keys in the private-keys-v1.d subfolder are recreated on the day I posted this question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think you should look for further help in the [GnuPG Mailing lists](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/) (click on "more information about this list" to learn how to post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the .gnupg folder in my home directory, after having exported the private keys. Then I started up GPG Keychain Access, with an empty list, and reimported the keys. This fixed the problem.